# Get album_id from Android Media Store

Tags: android, mediastore

If I know the path of an MP3 file on my Android device, how can I get an album_id so that I can start getting other values (such as album artwork) from the Media Store?

There are many examples of how to retrieve Media Store data on Stackoverflow but they all seem to assume an album_id is known first.

I've tried using the following but I can't get any matches at all:

```
Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{"*"},
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " = '" + songPath + "'",
    null,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC" );
```

Example `songPath`:

```
"/mnt/extSdCard/MP3/Pain/2002 - Nothing Remains the Same/04-Just Hate Me.mp3"
```

I test the result of the cursor as follows:

```
if( ! audioCursor.moveToFirst() )
{
  MyUtils.LogDebugf( "SEARCH FAILED::no results\n" );
  return;
}
```

Sure enough, my search fails. Why?

I have added images for albums using "Album Art Grabber" from Playstore. If I go into the phone's own music player, I can see the album artwork so it must have downloaded the artwork somewhere. Perhaps I shouldn't be using EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI after all??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searches will fail using `/mnt/extSdCard`

Adding this line yields results:

```
songPath = songPath.replace( "/mnt/extSdCard/MP3", "/storage/extSdCard/MP3" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get album id and get it from cursor object this parameters

```
 MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
 MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST
 MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID
```

***More information about the columns [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html)***